# How to add link icon to title area in react native component?

Tags: react-native

There is a `Event` component in my RN (0.59.9) app. Here is the constructor part of the code:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { SectionList, View, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform, TouchableHighlight, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import helper from "../../lib/helper";
import GLOBAL from "../../lib/global";

export default class Event extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Events',
    };
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._isMounted = true;
      console.log("props in Event : ", this.props);    
      this.state = {
        activeEvents: [],
        user: this.props.myself,
        token: this.props.token,
        group_id: this.props.group_id,
      };

      this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
    };
   .......
```

I would like to insert a icon link into title area to the right. The icon link links to another component called `Group` with `react navigation`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add a button in title:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html